Representation theory from Yoneda's perspective
I was studying representation theory when a question came to my mind.
Generally speaking, the Yoneda paradigm claims to obtain properties of a structure a by studying the morphism which map that structure into some other structures b (possibly also vice versa).
Representation theory is interpretable in this framework, aiming to discover properties of general groups (a) by studying their morphism to general linear groups (b). First of all, I'd like to know whether this point of view (representation as Yoneda) has been explored further or lead to other considerations, e.g. referencing to appropriate papers. I am aware that representation theory has historically appeared much earlier, hence the connection should be thought by a conceptual point of view, rather than chronological.
Anyway, this approach has historically proved to be undoubtedly useful, especially in relation to character theory: associating to each morphism a scalar-valued function (the traces) leads to many constants or scalar-valued functions (characters) which capture notable group-theoretic properties.
In spite of this convenience, I wonder if the choice of general linear groups has a conceptual reason behind, eventually linked to the above view of the theory.

I think Dirichlet initiated alot of the character stuff.

Lots of things are known about the matrix groups (aka classical groups), giving an obvious motivation.
If we have such a representation we can apply linear algebra among other things.
It gives us a more familiar way to visualize.
Now Yoneda generalizes Cayley's theorem,  which gives the so-called regular representation, into a symmetric group (which can always be viewed as a matrix group).
